# Java Programming Exercises?

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java coding. I took a camp for two weeks during the summer, and I learned stuff like loops, constructors, arrays, if statements, etc. Basically it was all in the console, I never actually learned how to make a program. I was wondering if any of you guys had any cool little exercises I could do to enhance my Java knowledge. (This includes things that I may have to research to be able to code).

Just an example - I felt like I would make a Hi-Low game.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        int num1 = generator.nextInt(9)+1;
        int num2 = generator.nextInt(9)+1;
        int num3 = generator.nextInt(9)+1;
        int num4 = generator.nextInt(9)+1;
        int right = 0;

        num1 = num1*1000;
        num2 = num2*100;
        num3 = num3*10;
        int code = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
        System.out.println("Lets play High-Low");
        while(right == 0){
            System.out.println("Guess a four digit number");
        int guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess < code){
            System.out.println("Low!");
            }
            else if (guess > code){
            System.out.println("High!");
            }
            else if (guess == code){
            System.out.println("You win! The code was " + code + "!");
            right = 1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

---

Yeah I hope that was as almost as efficient as I could have done it, but any ideas? I'm kind of out of them, and I keep seeing people recommend projects that actually run as programs like a file explorer, and I don't know how to do those.

Comment: And I think I could have used a boolean instead of checking if the int right = 1 so the code would stop looping

Comment: chess app, a pomodoro app, recursive apps, anything useful!!!!

Comment: fibonnacci, printing diamond *, converting 193 to string character, add or even number. more on http://projecteuler.net/problems

Comment: http://code-exercises.com/programming/ has a number of exercise in Java (with solutions). Three levels of difficulty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well first of all, Welcome to the community!
But regarding your question there are many exercises you are able to do. For example, if you are willing to spend some money, the book "Java for Dummies" (make sure it is the all-in-one version) has many tutorials for creating a working program ('pong' game clone, image viewer, drawing board program).
If you don't want to spend the money I suggest Udemy (https://www.udemy.com/). It has many great courses for the question you are currently asking.

Hope it will help :)